# Альтернативы эмулятору Android в AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор

Я только начал изучать Android-разработку и почти сразу появилась проблема: мой ноутбук не тянет эмулятор в Android Studio. Причём сам AndroidStudio работает достаточно шустро, а вот когда нажимаю на кнопку запуска то всё начинает виснуть, открывается эмулятор, но на нём отображается белый экран с логотипом Google, а потом AndroidStudio становится серым экраном и с надписью "AndroidStudio не отвечает". Я подозреваю, что дело в объёме ОЗУ на ноутбуке - 4Гб.

Собственно, мой вопрос: Есть ли бесплатные альтернативы эмулятору Android в AndroidStudio? Идеальным для меня вариантом было бы запустить Android-приложение на Java/Kotlin в браузере (как во Flutter).

P.S. На всякий оставлю характеристики моего ноутбука:
*ОС: Windows 10; Процессор: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU N3710 @ 1.60GHz 1.60 GHz; ОЗУ: 4Гб*

Comment: да, оперативы определенно мало. да и процессор не очень. лучший для вас выход - использовать реальный телефон.

Comment: идея хорошая, но у меня нет смартфона на Android.

Comment: ну так-то Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/ есть, он полегче будет

Comment: а есть бесплатная версия Genymotion?

Comment: С таким ноутом - только реальный девайс.

Comment: @ДмитрийКраснов, таки зачем платная? вот же по ссылочке переходим и все - https://www.genymotion.com/download/

Comment: @Andrew, понял, спасибо! Сейчас скачаю

Comment: @Andrew, а мне нужно скачать с VirtualBox или нет?

Comment: да нужно качнуть, насколько я понимаю GenyMotion это просто красивая обертка которая вам сразу выводит список ваших устройств и взаимодействует с VB

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @Andrew, если хотите, можете написать ответ (про Genymotion) на этот вопрос и я его отмечу.

Comment: да таких ответов тут по большому счету море) проблема так-то довольно популярная) допускаю что вопрос закроют по итогу :( потому что проблема популярная и решение уже есть)

Comment: Ясно. Но всё равно спасибо Вам! Вы мне очень помогли! :)

Comment: И Genymotion в VirtualBox будет лучше работать на таком железе?